# What does the sentence 多用心译 mean?

Tags: translation

I found this sentence in an essay written by a translator. I wonder if 多用心译 means 'translate a lot by heart', or 'translate diligently'? 心译 doesn't exist as a word, but could be created by the author as bisyllabic word because it is similar to 多改, 多试, 多想. '多用心译' can mean also 多用心翻译。in the two ways the sentence has a meaning. Which one of the two is correct?

Rosa

Comment: bkrs: 心译 lg. mental translation (technical term used by translators)

Comment: yes. thank you, butin this sentence 多用心译，means 'do a lot of mental translation' or 'translate very dilingently'?

Comment: it seems, "mental translation" = "translating in one's mind"

Comment: If you could get more context from that essay, that would be helpful.

Comment: ２ more compounds of type N(as instrument)+译 with greater usage frequency : 口译，笔译

Comment: the whole sentence is:然后多用心译，多改、多试、多想、多留心

Comment: the whole sentence is: 然后多用心译，多改、多试、多想、多留心. it can be found in an essay by 思果

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 然后多用心译，多改、多试、多想、多留心

In this case, I tend to interpret it as 多 用心 翻译 'translate diligently as much as possible'.

It could also be interpreted it as 多用 心译 'use 心译 as much as possible'. The thing is what would be 心译 like? Is it someone translating within his heart/head? If so, it would lose the consistency from other context: 多改、多试、多想、多留心.

So, 多改、多试、多想、多留心 conveys that translators should be very careful to make sure they could get all the translations accurate. That all suggests 多 用心 翻译 'translate diligently as much as possible'.

Answer (score 4):

A whole sentence would clarify the meaning. Do you have the sentence?

In my opinion, '多用心译' just means 'be careful when translating'. I can definitely empathize!

People say that the German President Heinrich Lübke once said to Queen Elizabeth II, "Equals goes it loose." They were at a horse race, he wanted to say, "It will start in a moment." but his English was not good and he translated from German literally.